# Installing Windows 8 with External DVD Drive

Tags: windows-8, installation, recovery-disk

I have Ubuntu on my computer, and I have Windows 8 recovery DVDs.  I do not have a build in DVD drive on my computer, so I bought an external one.  Will the external DVD drive be able to read the Windows 8 recovery DVDs if I remove Ubuntu from my computer first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optical drive's ability to read disks doesn't depend on operating system. It doesn't even know what's on your hard drive, it's just a dumb thingie that will do what the computer tells it.

If you wonder if you'll be able to boot from external drive then the answer is *yes*. But these days it's easier to find an empty 4 GB thumb drive than a working optical drive, so [installing from pendrive](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store?Action=html&Locale=en_US&SiteID=msusa&pbPage=Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool) is usually a better idea.

Comment: Excellent, thanks!  Can I put the 3 recovery DVDs onto a thumb drive?

Comment: Oh, I thought you have a single Windows DVD. It's a bit more complicated with recovery disks, because there's no standard way of making them and every manufacturer uses its own methods. It *may* be possible to boot them off a pendrive, but it probably won't be easy and/or doable without a lot of trial-and-error testing. Installing from DVDs may be easier in this case, unless you have a lot of spare time and don't mind learning how the entire booting concept works ;)